# Why won't my player character move?

Tags: python, pygame

I want my character to move up/left/down/right when I press w/a/s/d. What I think should be happening is that, for example, when I press d:

1. `main()` will "see" that there is an event happening
2. see that I pressed a key down
3. go to `player1.move()`
4. see that the key was d
5. go to `Character.move_right(self)`
6. update `x_pos` and `x_vel`
7. go back to `main()`
8. go to `player1.display()`
9. draw a rectangle wherever the updated `x_pos` and `x_vel` are
10. update the screen
11. "tick the clock"

This obviously isn't happening, though. Where am I misinterpreting what's going on?

```
import sys
import pygame


class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, surface, x_vel, y_vel, x_pos, y_pos):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x_vel = x_vel
        self.y_vel = y_vel
        self.x_pos = x_pos
        self.y_pos = y_pos
        self.size = (5, 20)

    def move_right(self):
        self.x_vel += 5
        self.x_pos += self.x_vel

    def move_left(self):
        self.x_vel -= 5
        self.x_pos += self.x_vel

    def move_up(self):
        self.y_vel -= 5
        self.y_pos += self.y_vel

    def move_down(self):
        self.y_vel += 5
        self.y_pos += self.y_vel

    def move(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    Character.move_up(self)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    Character.move_left(self)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    Character.move_down(self)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    Character.move_right(self)
        self.character = pygame.Rect((self.x_pos, self.y_pos), self.size)

    def display(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (255, 255, 255), self.character)

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

fps = 30


def main():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    player1 = Character(screen, 0, 0, 200, 200)
                    player1.move()

        player1.display()

        pygame.display.update(screen_rect)
        clock.tick(fps)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Problem seems to be, what the events are consumed by the `for` loop in `main`, so no events are left in the `for` loop in `move`.

Comment: You are aware that for each event different from QUIT, you create a new Character and assign it to player1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summarizing the possible errors:

As @tobias_k pointed out your events are already consumed. This can be fixed like this

```
def move(self, event):
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            ....

def main():
    player1 = Character(screen, 0, 0, 200, 200)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    player1.move(event)
```

Second, move the creation of the Character out of the main loop

```
def main():
    player1 = Character(screen, 0, 0, 200, 200)
    while True:
```

Comment: i would change `player1.move(event)` to `player1.handle_event(event)` Since if he adds a space to shoot something, that will not belong in the move method anymore.